# same data inserting twice in xampp mysql

Tags: php, angularjs, xampp

I am using PHP 5.6.30 version..when I try to execute the following code data is inserted twice.i am using register.php as view and app.js for http post service.

insert.php (database connection)

```
<?php 

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","user");
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->firstname);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->lastname);
$user_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->username);
$emailid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$data->emailid);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$data->password);
$mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$data->mobile);

$query = "INSERT INTO register(fname,lname,uname,email,pass,mobile)  
  VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$user_name','$emailid','$password','$mobile')";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query) ;
if($result == TRUE) 
{  
  echo "Data Inserted...";  
}  
else  
{  
  echo 'Error';  
}
```

?>

register.php:

```
enter code here
 <html>
 <head><title>Nav</title>
 <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
 </script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-
 route.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/header.css"/> 
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="RegisterController">

  <form ng-submit="rsubmit()" class="rform">REGISTER 
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" ng-
    model="firstname" placeholder="firstnamesss" ><br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" ng-
  model="lastname" placeholder="lastname" ><br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" ng-model="username" placeholder="username"><br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="emailid" ng-model="emailid" placeholder="emailid" ><br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="password" required=""/><br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" ng-model="mobile" placeholder="mobileno" ><br>
  <button ng-click="rsubmit()"  >Register</button>
   <a href="#/home">Cancel</a>         
  <br></h2>
  </form>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('RegisterController',function($scope,$http){  
$scope.rsubmit=function(){  

$http.post("insert.php" ,{
'firstname':$scope.firstname,
'lastname':$scope.lastname,
'username':$scope.username,
'emailid':$scope.emailid,
'password':$scope.password,
'mobile':$scope.mobile,

    } )
.success(function(data){  
            alert(data);  
            $scope.firstname = null;  
           // $scope.lastname = null; 

             });
    }
     });
```

Comment: Your PHP code seems perfectly fine, i assume the issue is you are sending the request twice. May you show us the code where you send the request to your server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit):

> Warning: Be careful not to cause "double-submission" by using both the ngClick and ngSubmit handlers together. See the form directive documentation for a detailed discussion of when ngSubmit may be triggered.

In your code you use both `ng-submit` *and* `ng-click`, so you trigger the controller (the request) twice. Just remove the `ngClick` attribute on the button/ input field and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `ng-click` from the button..Button used inside the form always submit the form..So you call the `rsubmit` function when click the button at same time when you click the button the form is going to submission.The form submission call again the `rsubmit` function..

Two types of ways for it
1.`<button type="button" ng-click="rsubmit()"  >Register</button>` - It disable the form submission power of button when you use `type="button"`
(or)
2.Skip the `action` attribute from the form.